# Can I make a dynamic collection in Steam based on playtime?

Tags: steam

I know that you can create a dynamic collection filtered by 'Unplayed' but I would like to create a collection along the lines of 'Favourites' and filter games I've played for say greater than or equal to 100 hours.

Is this possible in Steam? Or would I need a third party tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Steam itself doesn't support that (yet). Although it says dynamic you can only filter by static attributes, such as state or genre. The Steam forums have quite a lot of feature requests for collections, but as of yet they remain unheard.

The best you can do is...

- create a filter for *played* and sort by hours played or
- install only games you actively play and filter by *installed*

For everything else you'd need a third-party tool, if something like this even exists.

Comment: I'll go check if Depressurizer works with the new library https://github.com/Depressurizer/Depressurizer